# Order Objects with outer and sometimes inner position

Tags: c#

I have two classes:

```
public class OuterObject
{
   public int OuterPosition { get; set; }

   public InnerObject InnerObject { get; set; }
}

public class InnerObject
{
   public int InnerPosition { get; set; }
}
```

I need to order a list of OuterObjects: first, after OuterPosition. Then, only OuterObjects which have a InnerObject, should be ordered after the InnerPosition of these.

For example, if I have four OuterObjects:

A { OuterPosition = 1, new InnerObject { InnerPosition = 2 } }
B { OuterPosition = 2 }
C { OuterPosition = 3, new InnerObject { InnerPosition = 1 } }
D { OuterPosition = 4 }

I should get the order:

C { OuterPosition = 3, new InnerObject { InnerPosition = 1 } }
B { OuterPosition = 2 }
A { OuterPosition = 1, new InnerObject { InnerPosition = 2 } }
D { OuterPosition = 4 }

Is there an easy way to accomplish it?

Comment: Does this sort order not make any sense or am I just being thick here?

Comment: ..how does b come after c? i would expect CABD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ought to work.

```
// First, order by outer position
var result = list.OrderBy(o => o.OuterPosition).ToList();
// Next, rearrange the items with inner objects
var outerPositions = result.Select((o, i) => new{i, o});
var withInner = outerPositions.Where(e => e.o.InnerObject != null).ToList();
var withInnerPositions = withInner.OrderBy(e => e.o.InnerObject.InnerPosition)
    .Select((e, i) => new{newPosition = withInner[i].i, e.o});
foreach(var p in withInnerPositions)
{
    result[p.newPosition] = p.o;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<OuterObject> result = source
  .OrderBy(obj => obj.OuterPostion)
  .OrderBy(obj => obj.InnerObject != null ? obj.InnerObject.InnerPosition : obj.OuterPosition)
   //the second OrderBy preserves the original order in the event of ties in the second.


IEnumerable<OuterObject> result = source
  .OrderBy(obj => obj.InnerObject != null ? obj.InnerObject.InnerPosition : obj.OuterPosition)
  .ThenBy(obj => obj.OuterPostion)
   //ThenBy breaks ties in the first order with sub-sorting.
```

These may not give the order stipulated in the question, but some arrangment of these conditionals and OrderBy/ThenBy can be found to do so.